# How to use if condition in excel with list

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Requirement]

I have different categories and I want to check if it falls within that categories then display that name in cell.
For example, here **Name, Place,Thing** are list, I want cell **A10,A11,A12** to get fill with the category name that is mention in **C10,C11,C12**. i.e. my final cell value after giving value of **C10,C11,C12** it will be like this.

[image: Final Output]

As the list of each category will contain around 30-50 records so I want to know if there is any way where I can write it.

Please refer to the image for more details.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. And since your question has been answered, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Pkd You mean to say what ever value will be insert in any order in `C10:C12` corresponding category should be filled in `A10:A12` ?

Comment: @rajesh yes, basically want to map every value to name so that when I enter any of it, it will give me name..same goes for other categories

Comment: @pkd,, check now I've posted the Answer,, and I'm sure this will help You !! ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Write this Formula in cell `A10` & fill down:*

```
=INDEX(A$2:C$2,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$3:$C$6=C10)*(COLUMN($A$3:$C$6))))-COLUMN($A$2)+1)
```

**How it works:**

**INDEX,** returns a value of the cell at the intersection of a particular row and column, in a given range.

Here **MAX**, returns the maximum number from a range of cells.

In the Formula **SUMPRODUCT,** returns the sum of the products of corresponding ranges or arrays.

**COLUMN,** returns the column number of a reference.

**N.B.**

*As soon as you write values in cell Range `C10:C12`, formula will pull related Category names in cell Range `A10:A12`.*

Comment: Glad to help you @pkd keep asking ☺

Answer (score 2):

You really need to look at the syntax of the IF function. It takes three arguments, i.e.

- the condition
- do when the condition is true
- do when the condition is false.

You simply close the IF statement after the condition. That will never fly.

Next, you can't just expect text like "A-F" to be treated as a list of all letters in the alphabet starting with A and ending with F. That's not how it works.

You can, however, count how many times the value in A7 is present in the range A1:A6 using the Countif() function:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,A7)
```

If there is no match, the result will be zero. You can wrap that in an IF statement

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A6,A7),A7,"")
```

A zero result will be like "False" for the condition. You can either combine several IF statements like that for the other ranges ...

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A6,A7),A7,IF(COUNTIF(C1:C6,A7),A7,IF(COUNTIF(E1:E6,A7),A7,"")))
```

or, depending on your data, you may want to look at A1 to E6 as one block

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E6,A7),A7,"")
```

Your description of "it prints according to that" is not very helpful for what you want to see as the result. I assume it is the value in A7. Feel free to edit your question and provide clarification and better sample data.